# Recreate Window without destroying the Context

Tags: opengl, graphics, window, cross-platform, fullscreen

This question is about a graphics application using OpenGL. (At the time I am using the framework GLFW but I consider changing it.)

My aim is to let the user (as much as possible) continuously switch between fullscreen mode and windowed mode. This procedure should take less than a second and can occur during runtime. For example see the game Minecraft where the user can toggle fullscreen with virtually no delay.

The window recreation process doesn't take so much time. But the problem is, that closing the window destroys my OpenGL context and I have to reload all my shaders and buffers.

**How to recreate the window of a graphics application without destroying the OpenGL context?** (I would like to use GLFW but I am open minded about alternative frameworks or a own implementation.)

Comment: I will take a look on the library [libwm](http://code.google.com/p/libwm/wiki/Tutorial). It gives me independent access on windows and contexts. Maybe that is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Technically the OpenGL context is not tied to any window. What's important is, that the visual format of the window matches that of the visual format the context has been created for. It is perfectly possible to use a single OpenGL context with multiple windows.

The problem you're facing is, that frameworks like GLFW, SDL or GLUT don't expose this kind of functionality. It's a feature that definitely should be added to them some time.

You can however do it, when you create and manage your windows and OpenGL context yourself. The principal process of what you intend is the following:

1. select the visual format for the windows (PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR, Visual, FBConfig, depending on OS and graphics system)
2. create your first window and set the visual format
3. create the OpenGL context with respect to the first window as drawable
4. create further windows and set them to the very same visual format you've already selected.

You can now detach the OpenGL context from its current drawable (=window) and attach it to any other drawable (i.e. window) having a compatible visual format

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was looking for. It there any framework which could help me? I don't want to struggle about cross-platform myself. But since I don't use any controls like buttons or labels for my window, libraries like Qt or wxWidgets seem overweighted.

Comment: @sharethis: Nothing lightweight I know of. I think the best course of action was to add this functionality to GLFW and contribute it to the project. The question if of course, why you want to recreate the window with GLFW in the first place.

Comment: I just started with GLFW, but I am not decided to still use this framework for the discussed task. Is there a better way to go? Then I will face away from GLFW.

Comment: @sharethis: Well, GLFW is a fine framework. What I was wondering about is, why would you want to close the window and open another one?

Comment: That is because (I sadly think) I have to do this for toggling fullscreen mode. I don't know any functionality to do change an existing window to fullscreen or windowed mode in GLFW.

Comment: Ah, yes this is another limitation of GLFW. Except for MacOS X it's perfectly possible to turn a window fullscreen and back to decorated without recreation. But GLFW can't do it.